# 5VDC output converter going to 10V when IC is connected

Tags: converter

I have a pcb which uses ICs including two MCP3008. The voltage provided by the DC DC converter is to be 5V, and it is 5V when the two MCP3008 ICs are not inserted in the sockets. But when I place either of them in either socket (two ICs, two dip sockets) the voltage on that rail shoots to 10V.

What can I try to diagnose the problem.

I tried pulling both ICs, testing one at a time, testing each in each socket. Same problem happens.

Comment: Post a schematic of your circuit including the DC/DC converter.

Comment: I am using a integrated converter, TSR2-2450, did not make my own.

Comment: Still a complete schematic of your PCB is needed. Is there any voltage higher than 5 V applied to any pin on the MCP3008?